# What is the difference between Future and Completable future in this regards?

Tags: java, java-8, future, completable-future

### Use case example

What is the difference between using future vs completable future in the following example regards.

One of the main use, I read is with .apply() in completable future you can wire multiple methods.

Isn't it the case with Future to wire the methods inside a method() and call that method() {which wired them} in a separate thread.

I find both of them doing the same thing. Can anyone please explain?

```
class FutureExample {

    static boolean method1() {
        return true;
    }
    static boolean method2(boolean m) {
        return m;
    }

    static boolean method() {
        boolean v = method1();
        return method2(v);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); //initialize to 1 for stackoverflow question
        Future<Boolean> future = service.submit(FutureExample::method);
    }
}

VERSUS

class CompletableFutureExample {

    static boolean method1() {
        return true;
    }
    static boolean method2(boolean m) {
        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureExample::method1).thenApply(CompletableFutureExample::method2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s a weird question to pick up the simplest imaginable example of a `CompletableFuture` usage and ask about the difference to a construct that can *only* do that. What about `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureExample::method1) .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "whatever"), (b,s) -> some other calculation);`? Can you model that with a simple executor and a method? Or, how about that: `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureExample::method1) .thenApplyAsync(CompletableFutureExample::method2, EventQueue::invokeLater)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the first case (with `Future` only):

   - both methods are executed always in the same thread and this thread is blocked till both functions are done
   - no asynchronous exception handling
   - you can't easily combine/modify the execution chains: you always need to declare a new method for each function combinations

In this particular example the difference is not significant. The real power of 
`CompletableFuture`(or more generally -- `CompletionStage`) appears when you need to combine/merge the results of different asynchronous calls, handle exceptions of the entire chain, manage threads etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. CompletableFuture is used for writing non-blocking code by running a task on a separate thread than the main thread and notifying the same about the progress. It could has two types of result:

   - **Compleated**
   - **Failure**

*The main difference in this case is that you have possibility to complete a Future unit by using method .compleate(T t).*

2. With CompletableFuture you could attache Callable method:

   - `thenAccept(Function f)`
   - `thenApply(...)`
   - `thenRun(...)`

*With Future you do not get notified when it is complete, with CompletableFuture you have this posibility.*

I hope that I answered to your question. Have a nice day.